# fetching data from different dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I am new to python.I am having two dataframes one is df containing ID and Names and other dataframe is source having 3 columns MergedID,MergedName,Filename

In below code I am comparing my source data with df dataframe.

ideally code is working as if ID's from df column present in source MergedID column then create one column in df dataframe as match and write there True.but the next requirement is I need to know from which file the match is coming.How to fetch filename

```
def abcd(a,b,c):
if a!=None and len(a)>0 and str(a)!='nan' and a in list(c["MergedID"].astype(str)):
    match={True}
else:
    match={False}
    
    return match
```

```
df["match"]=df.apply(lambda x: abcd(str(x["ID"]),x["Name"],source) , axis=1)
```

Source dataframe

[image: source]

df dataframe

[image: df]

output should be

[image]

Comment: Your ques is not clear. Plus, paste the dictionary to generate input/ouptut dataframes. so, that people can reproduce the issue and solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```py
import pandas as pd

src_df = pd.DataFrame({'Filename': [f'Filename {i}' for i in range(1, 7)],
                       'MergedID': [7001, 1003, 3265, 1001, 6532, 1004],
                       'Mergedname': ['qwz', 'qwr', 'jkh', 'xyz', 'otp', 'abc']})

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005, 1006],
                   'Names': ['xyz', 'pqr', 'qwr', 'abc', 'prt', 'lmn']})

# Merge Together
merged_df = df.merge(src_df, left_on='ID', right_on='MergedID', how='left')
# Add Match Column
merged_df['match'] = merged_df['MergedID'].notnull()
# Filter and Reorder Columns
merged_df = merged_df[['ID', 'Names', 'match', 'Filename']]

# For Display
print(merged_df.fillna('').to_string(index=False))
```

Output:

```
  ID Names  match   Filename
1001   xyz   True Filename 4
1002   pqr  False           
1003   qwr   True Filename 2
1004   abc   True Filename 6
1005   prt  False           
1006   lmn  False
```

(The one-liner)

```py
merged_df = df.merge(src_df,
                     left_on='ID',
                     right_on='MergedID',
                     how='left') \
    .assign(match=lambda x: x['MergedID'].notnull())[['ID', 'Names',
                                                      'match', 'Filename']]
```